# What are the possible values of the other eigenvalue of $A.$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $M_{n}(K)$ be $n\times n$ matrices in some field $K$ and $A\in M_{n}(K)$ has order $m,$ i.e. $A^{m}=I_{n}$ for  smallest positive integer $m.$

> Now, if $A\in M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ has order $12$ and $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $A.$ What are the possible values of the other eigenvalue of $A.$

How can I start to find other eigenvalue(s) of $A$ ? Any hint or advice I will be grateful.

Comment: Have you thought about using the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: If the other eigenvalue is i, you can show it has degree 4. 

Otherwise it’s diagonalizable. 

If the other eigenvalue has multiplicative order $n$, the order of the matrix is $12=lcm(n,ord(i))=lcm(n,4)$, so $n$ is 3,6, or 12. Those roots of unity give you the answer.

Comment: @eric I cannot understand your comment. Is $A$ not in fact diagonalizable?

Comment: Ehh, maybe it is. It’s not directly obvious to me though and doesn’t change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $v$ is the corresponding eigenvector, then
$$\begin{align}Av &= \lambda v\\A^2v &= A(Av) = A(\lambda v) = \lambda^2 v\\&\ \ \vdots\\A^{12}v &= \lambda^{12}v\\v = Iv &= \lambda^{12}v\end{align}$$
Therefore $\lambda^{12} = 1$. This holds for *every* eigenvalue of $A$.

Now if I gave you some subset of the $12$-th roots of $1$, do you think you could come up with an $A$ with $A^{12} = I$ and having only eigenvalues from that set?